# Can an adjective be separated from its noun by a comma?

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis

> That would of course be denied by ministers, adamant the legislation is necessary.

[Laura Kuenssberg - BBC News - 15/09/20](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-54156794)

In this sentence, I am not quite sure what 'adamant' is doing. I very much like the construction but before I launch out and start using it I want to be more clear about what I am doing.

Is there merely an elipsis :

> That would of course be denied by ministers (who are) adamant (that) the legislation is necessary.

Or is 'adamant' a second subject of the verb 'is' (along with 'legislation').

It is almost as though 'adamant' is performing a verbal function, linking 'ministers' to 'legislation'.

I would be grateful for some sage advice on this, please.

Comment: Parenthetical, perhaps?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, indeed. But within the parenthesis, is 'adamant' still an adjective or is it performing a verbal function ?

Comment: Depends -- are you reading it or speaking it?

Comment: No, there's no ellipsis. "Adamant the legislation is necessary" is an adjective phrase functioning as a predicative adjunct. It's predicative because it refers to a predicand, "ministers", and an adjunct because it's an optional item in clause structure.

Comment: Predicative adjuncts are nor restricted to AdjPs. They can also be NPs (_A proud teetotaller, John stuck to water while the others drank champagne_) and PPs (_In a bad temper, as usual, John walked on ahead of the main party_).